# Has my graphics card blown?

Tags: windows

After cleaning temporary files with disk cleanup, and also after doing a complete computer backup with Windows Vista, all of a sudden the display on BOTH monitors just went west, it was so bad I could not navigate my desktop as everything was just a static mess.

I rebooted the computer and for a short while everything was fine, I accessed the external harddrive via usb WHICH had just be formatted and BANG, screen display went again, and after the monitor flashing on them off for about 3 times, I got the blue screen of death. NIGHTMARE. Now when I reboot even in bios, there is random green blocks and static everywhere. It will not start up except in safe mode, and when it safe mode, there is random blocks of green everywhere?

Has anyone any idea what the hell has happened? Any advice.

Andrew

Comment: You should always let the question be migrated naturally. Now you have lost the answer that you had on SF.

Comment: Great stuff, will keep that in mind!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It certainly sounds like the graphics card is (to use a technical term from this side of the Atlantic) knackered and quite comprehensively too.

I had one that would occasionally produce "static" images - very much like a stereogram image or the screen on [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/32112/pc-hangs-with-striped-screen-and-then-three-long-beeps-on-start-up), if it didn't just go completely blank. I replaced it well before it became the norm or affected the startup or BIOS screens.

I think your only solution is to replace the graphics card. Choosing one from the same manufacturer will save you hours of pain due to the old drivers not being uninstalled.

Answer (score 1):

Wow!

Ehh, based on the information provided, it could be the graphics card... but I don't suppose you wrote down what actually failed and caused the BSOD? This would confirm what it is.

if it is something Nvidia/ATI related it most likely is as doing a backup should not do anything to cause a crash like what you say.

Also, can you see the BIOS fine? Does the green start during or only after Windows has loaded (in safe mode)?

Comment: From the power being turned on, through bios, even in the bios setup, through the intial loading screen, I get green blocks, static.  Cannot boot up normally and in safe mode, I have to look through transaprent random array of green blocks of varying size, :-(